# Display an element of an array in an object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a object named `DTA`, in this object, I have an array named `PTF_DTA`.
Then, I want to display the `EXERCICE` variable.

Here is the [JSON](http://jsonblob.com/963192232341684224).

[image JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klSEE.png)

I have an error message =>

```
TS2339: Property 'EXERCICE' does not exist on type 'PortefeuilleDta[]'.
```

I don't understand how to solve this problem.

file.response.ts

```
export interface SearchDtaResponse extends ApiResponse {

    DTA: Dta;
}

export interface Dta {
    PP:  PersonnePhysiqueDta;
    PTF_DTA: PortefeuilleDta[];
}
export interface PortefeuilleDta {

    DTA: {
        PAYS: number;
        EXERCICE: number;
        STATUTDTA: number;
        NUMEROSUIVI: number;
        STATUTDTA_LIB: string;
 
    }

    PTF: {
        REFERENCE: string;
        INTITULE1: string; 
        COIN_LABEL: string; 
        ACTIF_LABEL: string; 
        ACTIF: number; 
   
    }

    QUALITE: number;
    QUALITE_LIB: string;
}

export interface PersonnePhysiqueDta {
    NOMFAMILLE: string; 
    NUMEROREGISTRENATIONAL: number;
    NATIONALITE: string;
    PRENOM: string;
    LIEUNAISSANCE: string;
    DATENAISSANCE: Date;
    PAYSDOMICILE: string;

}
```

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dta && dta.PP && dta.PTF_DTA">
   <div class="card" style="width: 60%">
      <div class="card-body">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
               <table class="table table-hover table-striped spaceLeft">
                  <tbody>
                     <ng-container>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Year</th>
                           <td> {{ dta.PTF_DTA.EXERCICE }} </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Registre national</th>
                           <td>{{ dta.PP.NUMEROREGISTRENATIONAL}}</td>
                        </tr>
                     </ng-container>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Maybe look into *ngFor..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the array is always length one, and the information is at the `0` index:

```html
<td> {{ dta.PTF_DTA[0].DTA.EXERCICE }} </td>
```